# Promise unhandled rejection behaviour

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to understand when does `unhandledrejection` event get triggered.
The listener is registered as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
    console.log('Triggered');
});
```

When I execute `Promise.reject(42);` I see `Triggered` printed in the console followed by `Uncaught (in promise) 42`

When I execute `Promise.reject(42).then();` the event listener is not triggered, only `Uncaught (in promise) 42` is printed in the console.

Why is adding empty `.then()` results in `unhandledrejection` event not being published?

*This is observed in Chrome (62.0.3202.89, 64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.*

Comment: Why are you using an empty `.then()` with no callbacks passed to it. What are you hoping to accomplish with that?

Comment: @Li357 - I don't see in either of those references why an empty `.then()` will prevent the unhandled rejection event.

Comment: @Li357 - I can't find where in the spec it actually says that `.then(x)` is treated differently than `.then()` for unhandledrejections, yet that's what we see in Chrome.

Comment: @jfriend00 Nevermind, I couldn't repro the OP's issue.

Comment: It does not repro for me here either: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eehk3cr7/

Comment: @jfriend00 It does not reproduce to me on jsfiddle either. Turns out it only reproduces in local files. When the same identical file is served from the server, it does not reproduce. Any idea why local files behave differently in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "local files"?  I don't understand what that is.

Comment: I meant an html file on one's local machine with some javascript in it opened directly in Chrome. As opposed to serving the same identical file from the http server. Apparently, they are treated differently by Chrome.

Comment: @jfriend00 Here is the minimum example of such file: https://gist.github.com/SlavaSt/ad41622bf9f8b048bc40b9a52eb52093

Comment: @SlavaSt - Curiously enough, it is `Promise.reject("x");` that causes the unhandled rejection event, not `Promise.reject("x").then();`.   So, it appears that having ANY `.then()` handler, even if there's no reject handler caused Chrome to not trigger the `unhandledrejection` event.  
Doesn't seem right to me.  I wonder if the `unhandledrejection` event is just not fully standardized and implemented yet in Chrome.